# Regex loop that creates variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, regex, loops

I have text documents (thousands) in a data frame (doc_id and description of events) and a list with hundred of pieces of text that I need to match against the text field in the data frame. I need to create new columns in the data frame for each one of the expressions in the list after matching the expression on each one of the documents.

Here a representation of my data

```
doc_id <- c("doc1","doc2","doc3","doc4","doc5","doc6","doc7")
event_desc <- c("yesterday I ate meat", "yesterday I ate tuna", "yesterday I ate chicken", "yesterday I ate tuna", "yesterday I ate meat", "yesterday I ate tuna", "yesterday I ate chicken") 
mydata <- data.frame(doc_id,event_desc)
```

the list will be

```
reg.ex.list <- list("pattern1" = "ate meat", "pattern2" = "ate tuna", "pattern3" = "ate chicken")
```

At the individual level (to create 1 column at a time) I was using regular expressions (stringr library) to find matches and then creating the column.

```
pattern1 <- "ate meat"  ##regular expression
mydata$pattern1 <- str_extract_all(mydata$event_desc, pattern1)   
##matching and extraction
mydata$pattern1 <- as.character(mydata$pattern1)
pattern1 <- strsplit(mydata$pattern1, split = ",")
pattern1 <- data.frame(ID = rep(mydata$doc_id, sapply(pattern1, 
length)), pattern1 = unlist(pattern1))
```

off course this cannot be extended for hundreds of pieces of text, so (unsuccessfully) I tried the loop below to do 2 things:

1. create the columns (and show me which docs match my regex)
2. create the columns using my regex as the column name

   for(i in reg.ex.list){
     nam <- paste(mydata, i, sep = "_")
     assign(nam, str_extract_all(mydata$event_desc, i))}

The regex approach might look odd, but I need to keep track of what expressions are matching what docs to later on bring more data using the regex as a key.

The expected result is a data frame with all my documents and next to them columns for each one of the regex.

[image]

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I added a representation of how my data looks like since I cannot load the actual data. Regards.

Comment: We would like an example that we can test solutions on. Your pictures of data illustrate the basic concept, but they are not importable to R, and they are not testable. (Though the size is just right - 10 cases with 3 expressions is perfect for testing!) Please share copy/pasteable R code to produce some actual examples similar to your real data. If your expressions use complex regex (e.g., look-ahead assertions, multiple capturing groups), please show that. If they are simple patterns, show that.

Comment: ok guys I added dummy data and the expected output. Tks